# Exercise 5, Section 6.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, minimal-polynomials

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Suppose that there exists some positive integer $k$ so that $T^k=0$. Prove that $T^n=0$.

**My attempt:** Let $M_T = \{f\in F[x] \mid f(T)=0\}$. Let $m$ be minimal polynomial of $T$. Since $T^k=0$, we have $x^k\in M_T$. So $m|x^k$. Which implies $m=x^i$, for some $1\leq i\leq k$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $\deg (m)\leq n$. So $m=x^i$, for some $1\leq i\leq n$. If $i=n$, then we’re done. If $1\leq i\lt n$, then $x^{n-i}\cdot m=x^{n-i}\cdot x^i=x^n$. Since $m(T)=0$, we have $(x^{n-i}\cdot m)(T)=T^{n-i}\cdot m(T)=0=x^n(T)=T^n$. Thus $T^n=0$. **Is my proof correct?**

To be honest, I’m not completely satisfied with my following step in proof: $m|x^k$ implies $m=x^i$, for some $1\leq i\leq k$. How to show we can’t write $x^k$ as product of two “wired” polynomial?

Comment: $F[x]$ is a unique factorization domain, and so every non constant polynomial has a unique decomposition into irreducibles. Just like every integer $\geq 2$ has a unique decomposition to prime factors. So if $m|x^k$ then $m$ can't be divisible by any irreducible polynomials other than $x$, as otherwise $x^k$ would be divisible by them as well.

Comment: I came up with above solution independent of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3371624/861687) similar solution. That proof kind of requires [minimal and characteristic polynomials of a linear operator have the same irreducible factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4612035/861687) result.

Comment: For an easy solution, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099421/let-a-be-an-n-times-n-matrix-for-which-ak-0-for-some-k-n-show-tha).

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the answer. I shouldn’t have skip section 4.5 (prime factorization of a polynomial) of book.

Comment: This is trivial, as roots $a$ induce linear factors $(x-a)$ by polynomial division. Now take $a=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Let $n=3$. What if characteristic polynomial is $x(x^2+1)$?

Comment: Then $x=i$ is a root. But $A$ has only real eigenvalues, namely all zero, so that is not possible. $x(x^2+1)$ cannot be the polynomial for $A$.